# getting same data from storing array

Tags: php

```
public productname = array();     

 public function prepare_product(){
        if(!empty($this->directoryfile)){

      //create empty class
      $imagesrc = new stdClass();

      $table = $this->directoryfile;

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";

      $results = $this->select($sql);

    while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

      //get all data from mysql.

      $productname[] = $row['PRODUCT_NAME'];

    }

    //i think here is the problem , i get 2 array with same data.
    foreach($productname as $map){
    $imagesrc->name = $map;
    $productImage[] = $imagesrc;
    }
}
}
```

my intention is to create a empty class new stdClass() and store the array like,
name:product_name, but i get 2 array with same data.

it suppose like this name:product_name1, name:product_name2; but i got return like this name:product_name2, name:product_name2;

how to i get the things i want ? if i store the data with using the stdclass() $imagesrc , i get data i want without the name title.

$productImage[] = $map;

Comment: I suppose this happens, because you store a reference (not the value) to $imagesrc here: `$productImage[] = $imagesrc;`

Comment: Does your query returns the correct results in the first place? before entering foreach has $productname array the correct values or duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the attribute 'name' every iteration and referencing the same object.

Jeff gave the answer.

If you absolutely need the second iteration for future purposes

Do:

```
foreach($productname as $map){
    $imagesrc = new stdClass();
    $imagesrc->name = $map;
    $productImage[] = $imagesrc;
}
```

Or:

```
foreach($productname as $map){
    $imagesrc->name = $map;
    $productImage[] = clone($imagesrc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line after `$productname[] = $row['PRODUCT_NAME'];` should do what you want to achieve and makes the second loop obsolet:

```
$productImage[] = (Object) array("name"=> $row['PRODUCT_NAME']);
```

As you can see, we can directly cast an array as object when creating it.

The problem you had was that you stored a reference to `$imagesrc` to `$productImage`, then changed the content of `$imagesrc` (to 'product_name2').